# Cordova Upload Files to S3

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3

I'm copying files off of cameras to upload to S3 in a Cordova App (on Android). Currently I download the file to the cache directory (I'd rather stream but I've not been able to work out how to do that)

I can create a little test text file and upload that no problems, so I know that part is working. It's just getting an image or video file and uploading that, which I'm having major problems with,

```
function downloadFileToLocalStorage(fileName, url, callback){

 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function(dir) {

var name = dir.nativeURL + fileName;
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(url);

fileTransfer.download(
  uri, name, function (entry) {
    callback(entry);
  },
  function (error) {console.log(error);},
  false, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
  }
);

});

}
```

Then I read the file and upload

```
function uploadAsset(fileEntry,callback) {

 fileEntry.file(function(file) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
//  var theBody = btoa(evt.target._result) (8mb file);
 var theBody = this.result//  (6mb file);

  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'video-processing'}});
  var opts = {queueSize: 2, partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10};
  var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: theBody, opts};

  bucket.upload(params,opts, function (err, data) {
    if(data)callback(data);
  }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
    console.log('Progress:',evt,formatBytes(evt.loaded),formatBytes(evt.total), parseInt(evt.loaded/evt.total * 100) + "%");
  });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})
}
```

This seems to be working, but there are a few problems:

- The reported upload size evt.total is nearly twice the original file size (4mb), I assume because I'm reading it into a blob. Should I be doing something else?  I've tried just uploading the read file directly.
- It times out before it finishes, it seems to get to around 28-30% then drop to 16%, then up to around 25% and it sticks around there for a while and then time outs.

Here is an example of the trace, usually it gets up to around 30-40% before dropping back to 11, comes up again and then drops. Very frustrating!

```
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 917504, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 917504…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 14%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1146880, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1146880…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 18%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1359872, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1359872…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 22%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1589248, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1589248…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 25%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1818624, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1818624…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 29%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 2048000, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 2048000…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 33%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 2277376, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 2277376…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 36%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 2277376, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 2277376…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 36%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 688128, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 688128…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 11%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 917504, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 917504…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 14%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1146880, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1146880…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 18%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1359872, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1359872…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 22%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 1359872, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 1359872…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 22%
awsController.js:43 Progress: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 688128, totalSize: 6171107, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 688128…} 6.171 MB 6.171 MB 11%
awsController.js:38 Error: Timeout(…)
```

Another example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the timeout to 0 and the queue size to 1 to fix it

```
 var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    httpOptions: {timeout: 0}
  });

  var params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: file.name,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: file.type,
    Body: theBody
  };

  var opts = {
    queueSize: 1,
    partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
  };
```